# Integrating jayway rest assured with serenity rest assured

Tags: rest, maven, cucumber, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I have created a framework for automation API testing using jayway rest assured and Maven. But the project requirement is to integrate it with serenity. When I integrate it I am getting many compilation errors. is there a way I can do this. Your expert suggestions are needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serenity BDD already provides an integration with Rest Assured framework.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-rest-assured
http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_testing_rest_with_serenity_bdd

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.